# pandas: error handling in apply on DataFrameGroupBy

Tags: python, pandas

How can one handle errors that occur while aggregating DataFrame groups yielded by the `df.groupby` function.

```
grouped_df = df.groupby(by=[FIELD_GID]).apply(_aggr)
```

where `_aggr` is a function that is called by pandas for each of the `DataFrameGroupBy` resulting from `groupby`. More specifically, `_aggr` aggregates the rows in each `DataFrameGroupBy` object according to some of their columns but in some cases these columns are not present or have NaN values so that the aggregation should just lead to an empty DataFrame that is returned.

For the sake of simplicity, assume that `_aggr` just always yields an error currently as shown below. Would it be best to create and return an empty DataFrame within `_aggr` or return `None` or raise an exception, for cases where the aggregation cannot happen?

```
def _aggr(df: DataFrame):
    raise KeyError
```

Comment: It all depends on context or analysis needs on what to return. I doubt there is best practice rule for all exceptions in aggregate functions. But this may be a design issue. Why are you aggregating on columns that do not exist? Since pandas/numpy methods can handle `NaN`, why can't your aggregate function?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, the aggregate function could handle NaNs, but I guess my question is, what the aggregate function should return in such cases? Just an empty dataframe, or None? I couldn't find anything about what the aggregate function is allowed to return in the docs.